# Dependent app configuration Wear Os, gradle vs manifest for distribution

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, publish, wear-os

Dependent app configuration Wear Os, gradle vs manifest for distribution

Hello, I need help, this is the first time that I see apps for Wear Os by Google, in this case I made an app dependent on the one on the phone.

Add the settings from the phone and wear app but when you go to "Advanced Settings" -> "Version types" -> Add "Wear Os by Google" and accept the Wear policies, it will be revised and rejected.

The only message I get by mail is the following

**Publishing status: Rejected
Your app has not been accepted into Wear OS. This does not affect your app’s status on Google Play.**

**Eligibility Issue
Does not mention Wear OS
Your app does not mention Wear OS in the store listing. Please refer to the Wear OS by Google app quality guidelines for more information.**

So it seems to me that you need some particular configurations either in the manifest or in gradle that I am ignoring, it should be noted that I have been guided by the official documentation but I have not had a satisfactory result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So does your app follow the [Wear OS by Google app quality guidelines](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/wear-app-quality#fn) and specifically the line that says "The app must mention Wear OS in its Google Play Store listing."?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Exact, that's why I don't know if it's the generation of the apk

Comment: This has nothing to do with your apk. You simply have to explicitly mention that your app supports Wear OS by Google in the Play Store listing. If you add that text to the description you should no longer see the error message.